# Flutter app screen getting cut with a white patch

Tags: android, flutter

We are facing a very weird issue with our Flutter Mobile app (Android version only). As displayed in the screenshot, the bottom part is getting cut, and the app loads only in the 3/4th part of the screen only.

This is coming in the released Playstore version only. In debug mode, this never happened on an emulator or real device. Also, this occurrence is very random and irrespective of the device model. If I close the app and re-run it works fine most of the time.

Flutter Version - 2.5.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's regarding the error.
When we run the app in debug mode the flutter shows a red box for error.
When we release the app with that error then that part is shown with a white box. So I think you are getting some errors on that part.
To check something wrong in release mode connect your real device with a computer/laptop then in your vscode terminal write the following command

```
flutter logs
```

then launch your app you will see your app all logs with errors.
If you don't understand post a comment on this answer I will reply.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying, in release mode when there is an error, the patch usually comes as grey in color. 
Another problem what I feel is this is very random

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik are you using something like `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` to get the keyboard height? That might cause this issue if the calculation is not proper when the keyboard is retracted.